# I cannot create a new server in my pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I want to create a server in pgAdmin 4 but it's not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws0Sq.png)

should actually work like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dOEB.png)

I'm a Linux Ubuntu 22.04 user.
I tried create a server, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Postgres service is not running on your device which is causing the server option to be hidden. You should start a Postgres server from the CLI and then connect to it using pgAdmin. You can use the following latest docs for setting up the connection afterward: [Connecting to Server](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/connecting.html) ,

Answer (score 1):

It was said that it was renamed register, you can check the comment on this question for more information [Postgresql pgAdmin is missing the menu item "create server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848002/postgresql-pgadmin-is-missing-the-menu-item-create-server)

Answer (score -1):

Click on this image: [image: Answer to your question]

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Where is the link?